# Touchpad mouse pointer lags/jumps 18.04 (dual-boot Windows 10)

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, mouse, touchpad

I've noticed a strange behavior, when using Ubuntu alongside Windows 10.
When I shut down or restart from Windows and then boot into Ubuntu - everything's working slick. When I choose the hibernate option from Windows 10 and then boot to Ubuntu, the mouse pointer makes small leaps and jumps in swiping direction for a little every few seconds, which obviously is really annoying. It's like it changes the acceleration of a pointer for a sec and then changes it back. The problem disappears when Windows is normally shut down and then boot into Ubuntu. Thanks for all the help in advance.